# in SwiftUI, Can't navigate from one screen to another screen using response from @State type datatype

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I want to Navigate from `HomeView` to `PopularArtWorkFilterView`. I used `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` for navigating. Navigation is fired but `PopularArtWorkFilterView` screen not found. Just this is `View All Popular art work` seen after clicking. Here the code i tried.

`HomeView.swift`

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    private let homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    @State var isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    HomeTopView()
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    
                    // Click event occures.
                    // But not navigate to PopularArtWorkFilterView
                    if isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked {
                        NavigationLink("View All Popular art work", destination: PopularArtWorkFilterView())
                    }
                    
                    PopularArtWorkListView(
                        popularArtWorkList: homeViewModel.getPopularArtWorks(),
                        isViewAllClicked: $isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked
                    ).padding(.bottom, 40)
                    
                    TrendingArtistListView(trendingArtistList: homeViewModel.getTrendingArtists())
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    
                    BidArtEventInfoView(bidArtEvent: homeViewModel.getBidArtEvents()[1])
                }
            }
            .background(Color("background"))
        }
    }
}
```

`PopularArtWorkListView.swift`

```
struct PopularArtWorkListView: View {
    
    let popularArtWorkList: [PopularArtWork]
    
    // Variable for tracking Click Listener
    @Binding var isViewAllClicked: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HeaderView(
                istClicked: $isViewAllClicked
            ).padding(.horizontal, 20)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(popularArtWorkList, id: \.id) { popularArtWork in
                        PopularArtWorkItemView(popularArtWork: popularArtWork)
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct HeaderView: View {
    
    // Variable for tracking Click Listener
    @Binding var istClicked: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Text("Popular Artwork")
                .font(.custom(.Urbanist_Bold, size: 20))
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("View All")
                .font(.custom(.Urbanist_Bold, size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.7))
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Toggle @Binding variable to track the click listener 
                    istClicked.toggle()
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Before clicking

[image]

After clicking

[image]

Comment: A `NavigationLink` is for all intents and purposes a button all you are doing is displaying and hiding the button that would do the navigating,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```swift
if isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked {
   NavigationLink("View All Popular art work", destination: PopularArtWorkFilterView())
}
```

you should use

```swift
NavigationLink("View All Popular art work", isActive: $isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked) { 
   PopularArtWorkFilterView()
}
```

Be aware that this approach has been deprecated along with `NavigationView` in iOS 16. If you are targeting iOS 16+ devices consider using `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`, and `navigationDestination` modifier:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        // ...
    }
    .background(Color("background"))
    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPopularArtWorkViewAllTextClicked) {
        PopularArtWorkFilterView()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your approach. It fixed my issues. But the problem is `init(_:isActive:destination:)` was deprecated in iOS 16.0. That's why, I have find out another solution.

Comment: Yes, if you are targeting iOS 16 + only, then it's better to use `NavigationStack` and `navigationDestination` instead

Comment: how to handle multiple event ? in my case, another text onClickEvent (AKA TrendingArtist ViewAll Text Click Listener). in navigationDestination(isPresented) is a single varible. How to handle multiple.? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AminulHaqueAome you need to use `path` property then  in your `NavigationStack` and use `navigationDestination(for:)`. You can take a look at this [article](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/21/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-deep-linking/)